# Docusign API with my applicaiton for insession signing process

Tags: api, soap, docusignapi, marray

I want to integrate docusign with my application and its work Like the linked given below.
how i will do that where user directed sign the my applicaiton generated documents and return back to my application.

"http://loancosample.azurewebsites.net"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Embedded Signing** feature of the DocuSign API to accomplish this flow.  With embedded signing the user can sign in an `iFrame` (or a `webview` for mobile) and once they are done signing they are re-directed to a URL specified by your application.

The re-direct URL will have a query parameter added to it which includes the action that the recipient took (i.e. signed, declined to sign, etc).  For instance, if your `returnUrl` is `https://www.docusign.com/developer-center` and the recipient SIGNED the document the return URL would be:

```
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center?event=signing_complete
```

Or if the user DECLINE to sign then the return URL would be:

```
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center?event=decline
```

More info available at the [DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center)